# Sending press events to the buttons of a running app in Android

Tags: java, android, events, operating-system

Hi is it possible to send a press event to a running app in android if I know the button name to be pressed?

For example if I have an app that has a text box and a button named SAVE, can I send press event to the SAVE button handler?

My goal is to automatically send press events to the GUI. Monkey randomly sends press events to random positions on the screen. But I want to be specific. If there is a button only send Press event to that button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button.performClick();
```

Comment: That only works for your own buttons, not for buttons contained in third-party apps.

Comment: Not being his own app wasn't in the acceptance criteria ;)  Never even occurred to me that he might be trying something like that.

Comment: Hi testing tool ROBOTIUM allows a user to do such things for android, I was just looking forward to knowing this.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi is it possible to send a press event to a running app in android if I know the button name to be pressed?

If the "running app" is yours, and you specifically put in code to support this, sure.

If the "running app" is not yours, and you are trying to do this from another Android app, then no, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Well, he could create a screen scraper and parse for the button he's looking for, no?

Comment: @BillMote: There is no such concept as a "screen scraper" in Android. Outside the device (and on certain devices with security flaws), you can take a screenshot, but that only gives you an image, not details regarding widget IDs. There is no way, in or out of a device, for App A to find out about the widgets in the UI of a foreground activity from App B, because they run in different processes (exception: emulators, using the Hierarchy View protocol from off-device). If the OP is looking for a solution that runs from a desktop, rather than on-device, there may be some more options available.

Comment: Hi testing tool ROBOTIUM allows a user to do such things for android, I was just looking forward to knowing this.

Comment: @Pbasak: Robotium uses Android's instrumentation test framework. It simply extends what Android already has with classes like `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. Moreover, it *only* works on apps that are signed with the same signing key as your test code, not merely "a running app in android".

Comment: Hi i dont understand this?
"Moreover, it only works on apps that are signed with the same signing key as your test code"

Comment: Hi I know this, what you mean by the test code? The code I am running to send the events?

Comment: @Pbasak: Yes. Robotium is a "testing tool", to use your own words. Hence, the code you write using Robotium would be "the test code".